# Which of the following is true in a tree: $E=O(V^2)$ or $E=O(V)$?

Tags: graph-theory

I am doing a computer science assignment.

In the assignment, I was asked to find an algorithm with time complexity $O(|E|)$. The input is a connected acyclic graph (a free tree). I have come up with an algorithm costs $O(V^2)$.

I am thinking of whether the time complexity of my algorithm satisfy the requirement or not. Because I know that in a complete graph, $E = O(V^2)$. However, in this question, I am dealing with a tree with $V-1$ edges. So the question is which of the following is true in a tree: $E=O(V^2)$ or $E=O(V)$?

Comment: That's the wrong question, because $O(V) \subset O(V^2)$. It could be fixed by using $\Theta$ instead of $O$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not. As you said $|E| = |V| - 1$ here. Hence, if your algorithm is in $O(|V|^2)$  it is not satisfied $O(|E|)$ here.